# html draw submit form in the same form using switch() JS

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I am new in programming and I need to make a DB insert using jsp. My probem is that I have my page with choose option ([see img](http://postimg.org/image/7u1rlslgf/)), and when I press "Display form to insert" button I want to have in the same page the rows (enter name and enter adresse) for this table from my DB.

the used code is:

```
<form action="javaservlet" method="post">

    Choose Table Name : 
    <select name="table">
    <option value="univer">univer</option>
    <option value="client">client</option>
    <option value="company">company</option>
    <option value="departament">departament</option>
    <option value="employee">employee</option>
    <option value="person">person</option>
    <option value="promotion">promotion</option>
    <option value="service">service</option>
    <option value="subsidiary">subsidiary</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Display form to insert">
    </font>

    <script>
    var ddl = document.getElementById("table");
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

    switch(selectedValue){

    case univer

            Enter name :<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
            Enter adresse :<input type="text" name="adresse">

    break;
    }
    </script>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use javascript like jsp. to achive this, change your java script like this:

```
<div id="txtbx>
</div>

case univer
    var temp='Enter name :<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>';
    temp+='Enter adresse :<input type="text" name="adresse">';
    document.getElementById("txtbx").innerHTML=temp
    break;
}
```